# Mapping a list of object models onto another single object

Tags: c#, linq, collections, aggregate

Is it possible to get one object from `IQueryable<Change>` collection and `Sum()` some fields in this collection?
I wrote this code:

```
Changes.Aggregate(new TaskInfo(), (info, change) => new TaskInfo
{
    TaskId= change.TaskId,
    UserId = change.UserId,
    Hours = info.Hours + change.BaseDiff,
    EffectiveHours = info.EffectiveHours + change.Diff
    // Other fields..
});
```

I know my collection contains the same values for `TaskId` and `UserId` fields.
Also I guess I can do as following:

```
var result = new TaskInfo();
foreach (var change in Changes.AsEnumerable())
{
    result.TaskId = change.TaskId;
    result.UserId = change.UserId;
    result.Hours += change.BaseDiff;
    ///... other fields
}
```

The first solution doesn't seems pretty because of constructing new extra objects and the second because of setting *Ids* fields every iteration. Is there any better solutions?

Comment: The second solution not showing that you setting Ids fields every iteration

Comment: Why you want in first solution get the TaskId and the UserID ?

Comment: @ArDumez Because I need to set them in to my `TaskInfo` class.

Comment: @ArDumez The task is to aggregate my diff's in to the business object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq Query like this:

```
    from c in Changes
    group c by new {c.TaskId, c.UserId} into g
    select new TaskInfo(){
      UserId = g.Key.UserId,
      TaskId = g.Key.TaskId,
      Hours = g.Sum(x => x.BaseDiff),
      EffectiveHours = g.Sum(x => x.Diff)
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about this but I have grouped objects in my collection already.

Comment: Also this function returns multiple `UserTask` objects with the similar values.